# How to access properties.properties file from outside of the war file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, properties, tomcat7, war

I am using Java 7, Tomcat 7 and writing my own servlet.

I want to keep properties file outside of the .war file. So i or anybody can changed it anytime.

Please let me know how can i access the properties file in the web application from outside of the .war file.

Thanks,

Amol

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Properties.load(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) method to load properties from a static location outside your war file.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("<<PathtoYourPropertiesFile>>"));
```

Comment: I don't know how safe or standardised this is but this worked for me and saved a lot of effort. Thank you.